# Cant login to my sites on AWS but I CAN login with the same database on my local machine

Tags: 7

I've loaded two different Drupal 7 sites on Amazon Web Services (AWS) Ubuntu instances. They both work fine and are configured mostly correctly.

**The only problem i**s, I can't login to either site using my Drupal username/password combinations! (either site). I've double and triple checked my passwords/making sure CAPS LOCK isn't on, etc. I cleared cookies and even tried the permissions [suggestion given in this article](http://alvinalexander.com/drupal/drupal-cant-login-after-upgrade-update).

No matter what I do when I try to login to either site on AWS I get a silent login fail. No errors, the browser just reloads and prompts me to login again. I know the username/password work because on my local machine for both sites I can login easily using the same database.

*Note: I, of course, imported the databases for both projects so they SHOULD have the same user data.*

Anyone know what else I can try?

Comment: Sometime it is due to the cookie domain, are you using cookie domain?

Comment: > Anyone know what else I can try?
Drush. eg, `drush st` and if you want to set new passwords `drush user-password 1 --password=f00oo0o0o0`

Comment: @tenken ok I installed drush on my ubuntu aws server and when I type drush --version it shows me the version I have installed (drush 8). but i can't use the commands you gave me. How do I target my site and the mysql database specifically?

Comment: Specifically, when I run the drush command you gave me from my root directory I get:
Command user-password needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you    [error]
will need to invoke drush from a more functional Drupal environment
to run this command.
The drush command 'user-password username' could not be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I fixed it. I had to run the following command:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Comment: I've been trying to resolve this issue for a couple of days and this worked!

Answer (score 1):

So the real problem was, when you said:

> I've loaded two different Drupal 7 sites on Amazon Web Services (AWS) Ubuntu instances. They both work fine and are configured mostly correctly.

You neglected to prepare your site for migration by putting it into a state which is ready to be deployed elsewhere, even a newly spawned, and default configured OS (with no prior websites running). Even if you use a tool like Drush and `archive-backup` command it's recommended when moving a Drupal site to clear-cache, and to disable clean-urls for example as webserver configurations may be different between hosts.

When moving a site you want it configured minimally so that it is simple to restore, and test, on the destination server and so whatever custom tweaks need to occur on the new host can be performed after deployment.

Other modules that can help with this for example is [Pathologic](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathologic):

> Pathologic is an input filter which can correct paths in links and
>   images in your Drupal content in situations which would otherwise
>   cause them to “break;” for example, if the URL of the site changes, or
>   the content was moved to a different server. Pathologic can also solve
>   the problem of missing images and broken links in your site’s RSS
>   feeds.